# Retrieve number from variable value and manipulate it

Tags: jquery

I need to get the value of a variable which will be one of "step1", "step2", "step3" etc.

then I want to get the number from that variable eg. get just "1" from "step1" and 1 to it.

so if the value is step1, I would end up with an another variable which has the value step2.

```
var currentStep = step1;
```

var nextStep =.....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have requirement of variables with incrementing numbers then consider using array it will be more straight forward.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duBuk/)**

```
arrSteps = [1,3,5];
```

To iterate through array you can use loop

```
for(i=0; i < arrSteps.length; i++)
   alert(arrSteps[i]);
```

Comment: Either this or make them properties of an object. And for what we can tell from the question, an array is what I'd go with too.

Comment: not what I'm looking for, all I want to do is just get the character of the variable add 1 to it then create another variable which has "step"+"newvalue.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to take a variable name and manipulate it as if it were a string, and call the value of the variable whose name is the new modified string value.

If so, I have two things in mind:

1. If these variables (`step1`, `step2`, etc.) are global variables, you can call `window[variableName]` to get their values. In your case, `window['step1']` should return the value of variable `step1`, and you can use jQuery string functions to modify the key values. For example,

   ```
   var currentStep = 'step1';
   var nextStep = 'step' + (parseInt(currentStep.substr(4))); //nextStep = 'step2'

   console.log(window[currentStep]) //prints 'value of step1'
   console.log(window[nextStep]) //prints 'value of step2'
   ```
2. If these are not global variables, you should use an object like so:

   ```
   var steps = {
       step1: "value of step1",
       step2: "value of step2",
       step3: "value of step3"
   };
   ```

   and call them using the same method as number 1 (except `window[currentStep]` would be `steps[currentStep]`. Or you can use arrays like in @Adil's answer:

   ```
   var steps = ["value of step1", "value of step2", "value of step3"]
   ```

In conclusion, what you were originally thinking of isn't good coding practice, but you can use workarounds like these to help you achieve your goals.

Answer (score -1):

You can also make a pair of arrays to match each step to a number.

```
var stepToNum = {'step1':1, 'step2':2, 'step3':3, ...}
var numToStep = ['step1','step2','step3', ...],

var currStep = 'step1';

var newStep = numToStep[(stepToNum[currStep]+1)];
```